# How to disable error like Eclipse while creating signed apk in Android Studio 1

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have problem in my Class, but when I run it its running good on my mobile using cable to android studio, but when I generate signed apk then I get class error like below

```
Error:Error: This fragment inner class should be static (app.browser.HomeActivity.MyWebBrowser) [ValidFragment]
```

I can't change class static because when I put static this child class context show me error, so please help me bout this question I want to disable this error when I generate signed apk. Please anyone can suggest me.

My Code..

```
public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {


private ActionBar.Tab iTab;
static String TAB_TITLE="Untitle";
private ViewPager viewPager;
static TabsPageAdapter mAdapter;
static android.app.ActionBar actionBar;
Context context;
 Button btNewtab,btCloseTab,btTabCount;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);


    context=HomeActivity.this;

    objectReferences();
    createDir();

    actionBar =getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    actionBar.hide();
    mAdapter = new TabsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(500);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
           // mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                PAGE_CURRENT=i;
            System.out.println("CURRENT PAGE DISCRIPTION : "+PAGE_CURRENT);


        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    });




}
```

//_________________TABS IMPLEMENTS METHODS__________________________

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
   }

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
      }

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
   }
public class TabsPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {


    public TabsPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return new MyWebBrowser();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
       return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return COUNT_TAB;
    }

}

//____________________________________________
//_____________BROWSER CLASS____________________
//____________________________________________
public class MyWebBrowser extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener,View.OnLongClickListener{

    View rootView;

    @SuppressLint("AddJavascriptInterface")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_web_browser, container, false);

       return rootView;
}
```

}

Hear i remove my content for personal reason please suggest me about this, Thanks men

Comment: could you provide more code?

Comment: I found no clue..I think you should be extending the ActionBarActivtiy for your main activity and for what purpose you are  creating the context instance variable and are you using separate class file for your fragment?

Comment: Thanks again replay, yes i, i use like DownloadManager which need baseContext and also shardPredferences , and also use Intent for start another activity, when i use static method in MyWebBrowser class then this all need remove static method, when without use of it error gone,project are run in device but not generat signed apk

Comment: you should use this instead of accessing context as u did, and  which method you define as static here i cant find.

Comment: MyWebBrowser class shout be static, but i want to declare it without static, reason is same as above comment, because static method give me error and without static my project run but not generat signed apk. and in above code i display MyWebBrowser class as public as i need not static

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should try to add following script in you build.gradle. (Must write in android{} tag)

```
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
```

When your release build generate an error by lint, the build task will not abort.

Comment: Wow,thats i want to need, Thanks a lt men,Thanks again, but apk generated but eroor still

Comment: Oh, it does't matter, just a lint error. You can find the lint report in: build/outputs/lint-results.html, and it will tell you how to fix the warning or error.

Comment: Thanks Bill, you give me new trick to see lint error, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Ok first you can try to change your class to statci like this - `Public class MyClass --> Public static class MyClass` or you can go to your eclipse settings then to lint preferences then uncheck marks where its written to fully check for errors while exporting.Or you can declire your FragmentActivity like static.But i would recomend you not to extend anything else but only activity and then implement the rest and declare FragmentActivity inside your MainActivity.Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your replay but i make and run project in Android Studio,And also i want to change class as static, is this one possible, and also we uncheck lint error in eclipse, is same like possible in Android Studio 1.

Comment: Can we use cunstructer? If yes then please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved error, just added script as below and best regard of Bill.

```
lintOptions {
abortOnError false}
```

Under android{

}

Thanks all men who give me answer